# Why is the code not able to find the file specified in the AWS S3 path, when I can find it manually?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a bucket called `my_bucket` and a folder in it called `Images`. I am trying to read the files (images) inside the `Image` folder.

```
file = pd.read_csv(some_csv_file)
X = file.values[:,0]

role = get_execution_role()
bucket='my_bucket'
data_key = 'Images'
data_dir = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
s = '/'

for img_name in X:
    seq = (data_dir, img_name)
    img_path = s.join(seq)
    img = imread(img_path)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-a273242ed30e> in <module>()
     43     img_path = s.join(seq)
     44     print(img_path)
---> 45     img = imread(img_path)
     46     img = imresize(img, (32, 32))
     47     img = img.astype('float32') # this will help us in later stage

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py in newfunc(*args, **kwds)
     99             """`arrayrange` is deprecated, use `arange` instead!"""
    100             warnings.warn(depdoc, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 101             return func(*args, **kwds)
    102 
    103         newfunc = _set_function_name(newfunc, old_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py in imread(name, flatten, mode)
    162     """
    163 
--> 164     im = Image.open(name)
    165     return fromimage(im, flatten=flatten, mode=mode)
    166 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2541 
   2542     if filename:
-> 2543         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2544         exclusive_fp = True
   2545 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://my_bucket/Images/377.jpg'
```

`377.jpg` is the first row in `X`. I checked manually in the S3 storage; this file is present there. So, why am I getting this error, and how to fix it? The only reason I can think of is, maybe the process of specifying the S3 path is wrong - but in the S3 documentation, the process to specify storage is given as `'s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)`. Moreover, in the last line of the error message, the filename is `s3://my_bucket/Images/377.jpg`, which is the path I navigate manually to locate the file in the bucket.

Comment: What are your bucket permissions? More specifically, what are the permissions on the files in your Images folder?

Comment: When creating the bucket, I gave read and write permissions to the bucket for myself.

Comment: What about the specific files? I've found that there is a difference, unfortunately - for example, whenever I change a static website of mine's HTML, I have to go in and change the permissions for those changed files back to 755. Unfortunately, however, if this was your problem, the error would probably just be "permission needed", not "no such file or directory"...

Answer (score 0):

if the implementation is in python, use boto3.

For example,

```
import boto3 
s3 = s3_session.client('s3')
object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_names,Key=object_name)
objectContent = object['Body'].read()
```

Refer : https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object

Comment: Firstly, I got errors: `NameError: name 's3_session' is not defined` and `AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object'`. I fixed those. Secondly, it does not read the images from the key folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the IAM role attached to your sagemaker notebook instance**, you have to give access to s3. Make sure you have given read access to your s3 bucket and all objects in the bucket /*. You don't have to use boto3.